# ArcGIS 10.1 Network Analysis- How do I get appropriate network dataset?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, network, multimodal-network

I have acquired London road dataset from the Open Street Map however after creating and building the network dataset in ArcCatalogue the solve tool could not return the routes because of errors no valid stops. That after I had enter the addresses as stops, No result was returned.

Olawumi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ESRI [Street Map Premium for ArcGIS](http://www.esri.com/data/streetmap) is network ready, and they have [datasets for Europe](http://www.esri.com/data/streetmap/europe-streetmap) too.